Comprehension using a collector does not collect its data
My understanding is that a map implements the Collector protocol and therefore can be used in the into: part of a comprehension. To try this out, I wrote the following program:
lt = [{"ab", "cd", "ef"}, {"x", "y", "z"}]
m = %{}
for c <- lt, into: m do
  IO.puts(length(Map.keys(m)))
  {elem(c,1),elem(c,0)}
end
IO.puts(length(Map.keys(m)))

I expected that m is set at the end to %{"cd" => "ab", "y" => "x"} and to see
0
1
2

being printed, but I got a 0 printed three times. It seems that nothing has been collected into the map m. Why?

(You could use Map.new/2 for this; m = Map.new(lt, fn {v, k, _} -> {k, v} end).)

Because that is how :into options works. Your code is the logical equivalent of
lt = [{"ab", "cd", "ef"}, {"x", "y", "z"}]
m = %{}

lt
|> Enum.map(fn c ->
  IO.puts(length(Map.keys(m))
  {elem(c, 1), elem(c, 2)}
end)
|> Enum.into(m)

IO.puts(length(Map.keys(m)))

So as you can see, there is no modification of m anywhere. What you probably wanted is:
lt = [{"ab", "cd", "ef"}, {"x", "y", "z"}]
m =
  for c <- lt, reduce: %{} do
    m ->
      IO.puts(Map.size(m)) # I use Map.size/1 there as it is faster
      Map.put(m, elem(c, 1), elem(c, 2))
  end

IO.puts(Map.size(m))

This will result in behaviour that you want.

Your forgot that variables are immutable: you need to use and keep the value returned by for.
The variable m will be and stay an empty map, it won't be modified nor rebound. In fact, it just set the initial value of the accumulator so using a variable here is not very useful, you can directly write into: %{}.
lt = [{"ab", "cd", "ef"}, {"x", "y", "z"}]
output =
  for c <- lt, into: %{} do
    {elem(c, 1), elem(c, 0)}
  end
output |> Map.size() |> IO.puts()

If you want to get the accumulated value, because for handles it for you and doesn't expose it, you'll have to use the :reduce as shown by Hauleth which is equivalent to Enum.reduce/3 if you prefer :
[
  {"ab", "cd", "ef"},
  {"x", "y", "z"},
]
|> Enum.reduce(
  %{},
  fn c, acc ->
    acc |> Map.size() |> IO.puts()
    Map.put(acc, elem(c, 1), elem(c, 0))
  end
)
|> tap(
  fn data ->
    data |> Map.size() |> IO.puts()
  end
)


But isn't it the case that a collector modifies the container it collects into? And if it doesn't, why do I then need the variable m in the first place? Can we write that code without the use of m? I'm aware that we don't modify a variable in a functional language, but my impression was that a Collector would break this paradigm.

for doesn't expose the accumuled value except if you use it's :reduce option because it handles it for you. :into just indicates the initial value of this accumulator, it's not a variable that get altered nor rebound.

No, it do not modify the accumulator, as there is no such thing in this case. The thing in :into key is just the value into which the values will be collected. It do not need to be variable at all.

In this case, I should be able to use into: %{} to achieve the same effect, shouldn't I?

Yes (as Hauleth said)


Values in elixir are immutable.
iex(1)> map = %{}
%{}
iex(2)> Map.put(map, :foo, :bar)
%{foo: :bar}
iex(3)> map
%{}

However, they can be rebound:
iex(4)> map = %{foo: :bar}
%{foo: :bar}
iex(5)> map = %{different?: "yes"}
%{different?: "yes"}

So while you cannot mutate what is contained inside value, you can rebind what a variable points to.
In the case of Map.put above, the operation returns a new datastructure that represents the original map with the change applied, without affecting the original map. If you want to preserve the result, you need to assign it back to the variable:
iex(6)> map = %{}
%{}
iex(7)> map = Map.put(map, :foo, :bar)
%{foo: :bar}

In your example, the comprehension is collecting the values, but you are not assigning the result to a variable, and the original m is left untouched.
